# Finding max row with highest value for a particular country in a csv file

Tags: shell-script, sed

I have a .csv file with entries like

```
Location,Indicator,Period,First Tooltip
Afghanistan,Malaria incidence (per 1 000 population at risk),2018,29
Afghanistan,Malaria incidence (per 1 000 population at risk),2017,27
Afghanistan,Malaria incidence (per 1 000 population at risk),2016,26
Afghanistan,Malaria incidence (per 1 000 population at risk),2015,15
Afghanistan,Malaria incidence (per 1 000 population at risk),2002,104
Afghanistan,Malaria incidence (per 1 000 population at risk),2001,92
Afghanistan,Malaria incidence (per 1 000 population at risk),2000,96
Algeria,Malaria incidence (per 1 000 population at risk),2018,0
Algeria,Malaria incidence (per 1 000 population at risk),2017,0
Algeria,Malaria incidence (per 1 000 population at risk),2013,0
```

I want to write a shell script that gives a country name as the argument to the shell
script returns and output like :

```
./scrip.sh Afghanistan  
For Afghanistan, the year is 2002; the rate is 104 per 1,000
```

Basically, for that country, pick the line with max Tooltip and then parse it to produce
the above output.

**My thoughts:**
I am not sure how to do this using a shell script.
There are two parts here one is selecting the max, and then once we have that line
split it over, find out the numerical values and print it out.
Any hints or ideas on how to procees

Answer (score 3):

Shell + awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

country="$1"

if [ -z "$country" ]
then
    printf "Country not specified\n" >&2
    exit 1
fi


awk -v FS=, -v country="$country" '
    BEGIN { tooltip = 0; found = 0 }
    $1 == country { if ($NF > tooltip) {found = 1; tooltip = $NF; year = $(NF - 1)} }
    END {if (!found) {print "No entry for the specified country"; exit 1} print "For " country " the year is " year "; the rate is " tooltip " per 1,000"}' file.csv
```

You didn't specify what's the name of the file so I used `file.csv`. Usage:

```
$ ./script.sh Afghanistan
For Afghanistan the year is 2002; the rate is 104 per 1,000
$ ./script.sh abc
No entry for the specified country
```

Comment: that was awesome. Please give some hints on how to do a similar thing, but now say the argument to the script is the year, and we want to find out the country which had the max entry for that year and display the exact details.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sed 's/ \+\([^,]*\),[^(]*(\([^0-9]*[0-9 ]*\)[^,]*,\([^,]*\),\(.*\)/For \1, the year is \3; the rate is \4 \2/' <(sed -n "/$1/p" input_file | sort -t',' -rnk4 | head -1)
```

```
$ ./script.sh Afghanistan
For Afghanistan, the year is 2002; the rate is 104 per 1 000
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting solution with `awk`:

#### script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
grep "$1" input.csv|sort -n -k 3 -t ","|tail -1|awk -F, '{gsub(" ","",$1);printf "For %s, the year is %d; the rate is %d per 1,000\n",$1,$3,$4}'
```

Comment: The column in `sort` is wrong. `grep "$1" input.csv|sort -n -k 4 -t ","|tail -1|awk -F, '{gsub(" ","",$1);printf "For %s, the year is %d; the rate is %d per 1,000\n",$1,$3,$4}'`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Perl script that will do what you ask. It's easy to extend if you need additional information later. It should work with the system Perl on any Unix/Linux box from the last 15 years or so.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.010;
use warnings;
use strict;

my $country = shift // die "Usage: $0 <country>\n";

my @rows = sort { $b->[3] <=> $a->[3] } 
           grep { $_->[0] eq $country } 
            map { chomp;[ split ',' ] } <>;

die "Country `$country' not found\n" if @rows == 0;

my $max = $rows[0];

say "For $country, the year is $max->[2]; the rate is $max->[3] per 1,000";
```

Sample output:

```
For Afghanistan, the year is 2002; the rate is 104 per 1,000
```

The script reads each line of STDIN with `<>`. The `map`, `grep`, and `sort` are done in order from bottom up: the `map` removes newlines (`chomp`) and splits the line on commas.

The `grep` then searches for rows where the country (`$_->[0]`; first column) is equal to `$country`.

Finally the `sort` sorts in reverse numerical order by the fourth column. (`$_->[3]`). So now we have all of the, say, Afghanistan rows, and the one with the highest value is at the top.

So now it's easy. We can just set `$max` to the first row (`$rows[0]`), and then it's just a matter of outputting your desired string.